# Class not found LocationAvailability

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

Migrating my android app to the latest google play services location I have this crash:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4458)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700 (ActivityThread.java:261)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2165)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:238)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:355)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8080)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1026)
Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.location.LocationAvailability
  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator (Parcel.java:3417)
  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable (Parcel.java:3325)
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:3227)
  at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:3624)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked (BaseBundle.java:292)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel (BaseBundle.java:236)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey (BaseBundle.java:516)
  at android.content.Intent.hasExtra (Intent.java:8326)
  at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult.hasResult (com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@@21.0.1:1)
  at com.xxx.yyy.receivers.LocationReceiver.onReceive (LocationReceiver.java:27)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4449)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.location.LocationAvailability
  at java.lang.Class.classForName
  at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:454)
  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator (Parcel.java:3391)
```

I'm using Android Studio 2022.1.1 Patch 2.

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:19.0.1'
}
```

Is it a google play services bug?

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself, yes, it is :( It seems totally random actually and all the issue in the android issue tracker are closed as "Won't fix". The only solution is to keep the version 20.0.0, it still works.

Comment: If you are able to reproduce this crash or have any additional information, consider chiming in on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/265809643